I wonder why lightning-record-picker shows error when I add disabled attribute to them
I have lightning record picker with disabled attribute set to false at init.
Following lwc error occurs when page with component is opened.
I wonder if it is some sort of bug or I missing something here?
<lightning-layout-item size="3" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="3">
            <lightning-record-picker
                label="MyRecord"
                data-name="recordId"
                placeholder="Search"
                object-api-name="Account"
                value={myRecord}
                onchange={handleValueChange}
                disabled={disablePicker}
                required>
            </lightning-record-picker>



Are you using refs in your own code?

Nope. I do not have any refs in my own code
